# How can I reinstall OSX on a Macbook Pro with a blank hard drive and no Apple "restore" functionality

Tags: macos, reinstall, refind

I need to reinstall OSX on a Macbook pro that I've completely wiped of all original Mac-related partitions.

(side note: the only reason I need to reinstall Mac OSX is to perform the Boot Camp driver download that is impossible without a working OSX installation. I've tried installing every single Boot Camp driver from 3.0 up to 5.0+ and have failed to find the correct drivers for my keyboard, touchpad, display, etc. for Windows 10)

Because I only have access to Linux and Windows operating systems, I've tried the following:

1) every possible boot keyboard combination to restore the OSX install (command + r, command + option + r ), etc.

2) Installing an OSX .dmg image to a DVD and USB and attempting to boot

- DVD boot will hang on the gray screen, spin the DVD, and fail to boot from the DVD and continue booting into Linux/Windows. The DVD was burned using TransMac, and I've tried three different .dmg images that are all unable to boot
- USB's made with TransMac do not list themselves on the Apple boot menu (holding option) or in a Refind menu (the USB images aren't found in the possible boot options)
- Other USBs and DVDs will boot fine; in short I haven't had any success booting anything .dmg-related

Any help reinstalling OSX would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: did you try linux command "lspci" or "lsusb" to get the driver info ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty experienced with linux and I've tried both of those to get driver information, unfortunately Apple is awful with documentation and have specific drivers that must be downloaded from Apple sources; specifically the keyboard and display drivers are the most lacking and require drivers directly from Apple.

Comment: To amend my above comment, the drivers I'm looking for are for Windows 10, which are only available from Apple sources. On linux, I've been able to find all the appropriate drivers without any issues!

Comment: i just wondering... if you have linux. maybe this will this help.
1, make a hfs+ (boot flag) partition with gparted.
2. convert the dmg to iso. 
3. put the iso content inside the hfs+ with dd command.
4. reboot with GRUB RESCUE live cd. 
5. detect the partitions.. 
6. try to boot.

Answer (score 0):

with extra mac theres a solution: putting your "bad" mac in target disk mode and connecting with another "good" mac by firewire or thunderbolt.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option since I only have access to this one Macbook Pro

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to perform an internet recovery? You can accomplish this by pressing Option-Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R at startup.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: Yes, both of those fail to do anything and continue to normal Linux or Windows boot.